# Submit Buttons in Dynamics 365 Adaptive Card do not render in Teams

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, power-automate, adaptive-cards

I have the following problem with Adaptive Card: whenever I send one of them with a Flow in Teams, the Action.Http - Submit button do not render. Here's a very simple example to show the problem:

I've created a very simple card from the card designer : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xiyg4.png, here's the json used:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "id": "32eb7bf4-a7a7-b810-e2a1-454672288641",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Http",
                    "id": "45b64937-d849-aa7b-5feb-730f43db0133",
                    "title": "Submit",
                    "url": "https://messagecardplaygroundfn.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpPost?code=zJaYHdG4dZdPK0GTymwYzpaCtcPAPec8fTvc2flJRvahwigYWg3p0A==",
                    "method": "POST"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "padding": "Default"
}
```

Then I've created a simple flow just to make sure it is delivered by a bot in Microsoft Teams, and this is the output. Even with different sample code, the Action.Http button fails to render.
Could you help me? Let me know whether I can provide extra information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adaptive card action `Action.Http` POST is not supported in [Microsoft-Teams]

see below documentation for additional detail and context.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions#adaptive-cards-actions

You can use an `Action.Submit` to get a response back to your Flow and then you can do a POST from your Flow using a HTTP or HTTP-AAD Action.